# Help with mod_rewrite

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm trying to get mod_rewrite working with the following URLs:

```
/events.php?view=details&id=$var
/events.php?view=edit&id=$var
```

Obviously my goal is to have **/events/details/$var** and **/events/edit/$var** be my actual URL's, and $var is an unique ID.

**My .htaccess file**

```
RewriteEngine On

# redirect 301 /events.php http://www.google.com
# If the rule above is active, it does redirect to google.com, 
# so .htaccess is working

RewriteRule ^events/([^/]*)/([^/]*)\$ /events.php?view=$1&id=$2 [L]
```

Currently when I go to `/events/details/$var` it's displaying `/events.php` but not picking up the variables being passed in.

Any help would be appreciated!

***Update:*** I removed the .php mentioned by OverZealous. /events/details/$var still displays /events.

```
// From events.php
echo $_REQUEST['view']; //returns nothing
```

***Update2:***
I enabled the mod_rewrite log (level 5) and got the following output: (I stripped out the IP, date, my domain details etc)

```
[sid#7fc6d76f5608][rid#7fc6d79ad908/subreq] (3) [perdir /var/www/webroot/] add path info postfix: /var/www/webroot/events.php -> /var/www/webroot/events.php/details/35
[sid#7fc6d76f5608][rid#7fc6d79ad908/subreq] (3) [perdir /var/www/webroot/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/webroot/events.php/details/35 -> events.php/details/35
[sid#7fc6d76f5608][rid#7fc6d79ad908/subreq] (3) [perdir /var/www/webroot/] applying pattern '^events/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$' to uri 'events.php/details/35'
[sid#7fc6d76f5608][rid#7fc6d79ad908/subreq] (1) [perdir /var/www/webroot/] pass through /var/www/webroot/events.php

[sid#7fc6d76f5608][rid#7fc6d79a88e8/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/webroot/] add path info postfix: /var/www/webroot/events.php -> /var/www/webroot/events.php/details/35
[sid#7fc6d76f5608][rid#7fc6d79a88e8/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/webroot/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/webroot/events.php/details/35 -> events.php/details/35
[sid#7fc6d76f5608][rid#7fc6d79a88e8/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/webroot/] applying pattern '^events/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$' to uri 'events.php/details/35'
[sid#7fc6d76f5608][rid#7fc6d79a88e8/initial] (1) [perdir /var/www/webroot/] pass through /var/www/webroot/events.php

[sid#7fc6d76f5608][rid#7fc6d7a597c8/subreq] (3) [perdir /var/www/webroot/] add path info postfix: /var/www/webroot/details -> /var/www/webroot/details/35
[sid#7fc6d76f5608][rid#7fc6d7a597c8/subreq] (3) [perdir /var/www/webroot/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/webroot/details/35 -> details/35
[sid#7fc6d76f5608][rid#7fc6d7a597c8/subreq] (3) [perdir /var/www/webroot/] applying pattern '^events/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$' to uri 'details/35'
[sid#7fc6d76f5608][rid#7fc6d7a597c8/subreq] (1) [perdir /var/www/webroot/] pass through /var/www/webroot/details
```

Comment: Problem solved - [MultiViews was enabled][1] by default.

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/998491/why-is-my-variable-not-being-put-into-get

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you have `\.php` at the end?  Do you want the URLs to be `/events/details/123.php`?  Because that's not what your example is.

I think you want your rewrite rule to look like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^events/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /events.php?view=$1&id=$2 [L]
```

Comment: Oops, that wasn't meant to be there. I'd been playing around with an online htaccess generator and that must have snuck in. Even with the updated code it is still not returning the variables being passed in. Thanks for your response!

Comment: Well, the next step is to enable the mod_rewrite log, which will allow you to see if the rewrite is happening or not: http://www.easymodrewrite.com/guide-logging

Comment: Good idea. I enabled it and have added the log output above. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I think you are visiting `/details/35`, not `/events/details/35` - see, it says `pass through /var/www/webroot/details`, meaning it didn't apply any pattern.

Comment: I posted about the multiviews right as you added this. Thanks for your help and for pointing me towards the log.